# PuLP: Objective Function: Concatenate multiple lpSum

Tags: python, pulp

I am trying to concatenate several `lpSum` expressions to one long expression which shall be my objective function. However, my attempts on merging these expressions in an elegant way lead to undesired results.

I want something like this:

```python
a = pulp.lpSum(...)
b = pulp.lpSum(...)
c = pulp.lpSum(...)

prob += a + b - c
```

More concrete to my code:

```python
    alloc_prob = pulp.LpProblem("Supplier Allocation Problem", pulp.LpMinimize)

    TPC_func = pulp.lpSum(X[s][p]*procCosts[s][p] for s in supplier for p in 
    project), "Total Procurement Costs"
    TTC_func = pulp.lpSum(X[s][p]*transCosts[s][p] for s in supplier for p in 
    project), "Total Transportation Costs (incl. taxes/duties)"
    TD_func = pulp.lpSum(X_SEP[c][1]*discountFactor['Bonus / ton [€/t]'][c] for 
    c in company), "Total Discounts"`

    # Objective function: TPC + TTC - TD -> min
    alloc_prob += TPC_func  + TTC_func - TD_func
```

I already tried different nested approaches, e.g.:

```python
    prob += [pulp.lpSum(X[s][p]*procCosts[s][p] + X[s][p]*transCosts[s][p] for s 
    in supplier for p in project) - pulp.lpSum(X_SEP[c][1]*discountFactor['Bonus 
    / ton [€/t]'][c] for c in company)]
```

The output does what it should. However, this is neither a nice code nor can it be assigned to the objective function. Is there a smart way of implementing?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! What error to you get with your original code (with the separate sums combined?). Are you able to provided a minimal working example (full code with minimal input data so that I can try running it).

Comment: The solution from [Stuart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54225149/10922265) worked fine and solved the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the error, I can be 100% sure but I think the name that you are including in the lpsum is causing the problem try the following

```
alloc_prob = pulp.LpProblem("Supplier Allocation Problem", pulp.LpMinimize)

TPC_func = pulp.lpSum(X[s][p]*procCosts[s][p] for s in supplier for p in 
project)
TTC_func = pulp.lpSum(X[s][p]*transCosts[s][p] for s in supplier for p in 
project)
TD_func = pulp.lpSum(X_SEP[c][1]*discountFactor['Bonus / ton [€/t]'][c] for 
c in company)

# Objective function: TPC + TTC - TD -> min
alloc_prob += TPC_func  + TTC_func - TD_func
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! I didn't come up with the idea of removing the names - do you know why the naming causes a problem?